# awk - find pattern in line and remove it together with an upstream part

Tags: bash, search, awk

I have initially filtered my text file to contain only those lines that have a pattern identified (in this case it's "TCTGTACTATATTG"). Now from the resulting file I want to delete this pattern from each line that contains it, together with the upstream characters.
What is the best way to do that with AWK?

Here is my input:

```
@DGTKZQN1:384:C364AACXX:1:1109:19757:66886 2:N:0:GTGAAA
AACAGTTTCTGTACTATATTGACTCATAAGAGTGGTTTAATACGAAGGGAGGAGAAGTTTCCTGGAAATAATCGATTTCCTAGCTTTTAGTTGCAATAAT
+
CCCFFFFFHHHHDIIJJJJJJJJJIIJEIJHHCFGFFGHIIIIJGGIJGG@GHIGEEFDGGIGIJJIEHGIEHHHEDFFFDEEEDDEDDCCDBDDDCDDD
@DGTKZQN1:384:C364AACXX:1:1109:20360:66756 2:N:0:GTGAAA
TTTCTGTACTATATTGGGTGTGAGAAGTAATGGTGCACTCCACAGACCTCCAGTGGCTGCTTGTTCGCCAGAACAGCAAATTTCTGCAGAAGCGCAAAAG
+
@@CFFFFFHHHGHIIIJI;GCGGIIIJFHIIJGEDGGIJIICBDFIIIIJHIIGHIDHGEEHGHHIIJHGD?DDFEECEDDDDCDCCDDDCDDDDDDBC>
@DGTKZQN1:384:C364AACXX:1:1109:21207:66784 2:N:0:GTGAAA
AACAGTTTCTGTACTATATTGTACGTTGTGGATTATTAAAGGGAATAAAAGTGGTAGATTGTGCAGTTGAGGCAGGCTCTCAACTGTGAAACAGCGGTGG
+
@@CFFBDDFHBDCGG<?:CEEAFEEF@A3<?<3C>FEGHGG@DB?8BF@G>?0909??DF>HE@C=)8CEH9DHCB:AED>?C@6>C;6>C3?3=@B8B=
@DGTKZQN1:384:C364AACXX:1:1109:21026:66836 2:N:0:GTGAAA
AGAACAGTTTCTGTACTATATTGTTATACTTCTGTTGTGGGTGTAGAGTTTTCTCCGGCGTTGGCTTCAATGGAATAAGGCACGAGATGAATCCGTGGAG
+
@@@FFFFDHHHDHHIIJJEHHJGJJIGIIEIIIIEHEGHIJDF?DGEE4??DG@FGEG:FHHHHF@D@CEACEEEDDDCCCDDBDDDDDDDACDB??>BD
```

The output should be like this:

```
@DGTKZQN1:384:C364AACXX:1:1109:19757:66886 2:N:0:GTGAAA
ACTCATAAGAGTGGTTTAATACGAAGGGAGGAGAAGTTTCCTGGAAATAATCGATTTCCTAGCTTTTAGTTGCAATAAT
+
CCCFFFFFHHHHDIIJJJJJJJJJIIJEIJHHCFGFFGHIIIIJGGIJGG@GHIGEEFDGGIGIJJIEHGIEHHHEDFFFDEEEDDEDDCCDBDDDCDDD
@DGTKZQN1:384:C364AACXX:1:1109:20360:66756 2:N:0:GTGAAA
GGTGTGAGAAGTAATGGTGCACTCCACAGACCTCCAGTGGCTGCTTGTTCGCCAGAACAGCAAATTTCTGCAGAAGCGCAAAAG
+
@@CFFFFFHHHGHIIIJI;GCGGIIIJFHIIJGEDGGIJIICBDFIIIIJHIIGHIDHGEEHGHHIIJHGD?DDFEECEDDDDCDCCDDDCDDDDDDBC>
@DGTKZQN1:384:C364AACXX:1:1109:21207:66784 2:N:0:GTGAAA
TACGTTGTGGATTATTAAAGGGAATAAAAGTGGTAGATTGTGCAGTTGAGGCAGGCTCTCAACTGTGAAACAGCGGTGG
+
@@CFFBDDFHBDCGG<?:CEEAFEEF@A3<?<3C>FEGHGG@DB?8BF@G>?0909??DF>HE@C=)8CEH9DHCB:AED>?C@6>C;6>C3?3=@B8B=
@DGTKZQN1:384:C364AACXX:1:1109:21026:66836 2:N:0:GTGAAA
TTATACTTCTGTTGTGGGTGTAGAGTTTTCTCCGGCGTTGGCTTCAATGGAATAAGGCACGAGATGAATCCGTGGAG
+
@@@FFFFDHHHDHHIIJJEHHJGJJIGIIEIIIIEHEGHIJDF?DGEE4??DG@FGEG:FHHHHF@D@CEACEEEDDDCCCDDBDDDDDDDACDB??>BD
```

I've already tried using awk and split function, but I'm struggling with using string as field separator.

Comment: your desired result/output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like simple `sed` should work for you:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^.*TCTGTACTATATTG//g' file
```

Using awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/^.*TCTGTACTATATTG/, "")} 1' file
```

But using sed also gives you benefit of inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i.bak 's/.*TCTGTACTATATTG//g' file
```